# Primfaces 6.2 upload file with Spring Boot 2.1

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I am trying to upload a file with Primefaces 6.2 and Spring Boot 2.1 I think I have everything well configured but I can not upload file. When I am trying to upload file I see loading on the page but in console I have no logs and my debbuger do not stoping on the breakpoint on handler function.

My .xhtml form:

```
<h:form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:fileUpload value="#{estimateState.file}" skinSimple="true" label="Wybierz plik"
                      update="growl" mode="advanced" auto="true"
                      fileUploadListener="#{estimateController.handleFileUpload}"/>
</h:form>
```

File handler

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    informationMessage(getState().getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
}
```

Beans which initialize PrimeFaces

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean primeFacesFileUploadFilter(@Autowired ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet> facesServletServletRegistrationBean) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(new org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter());
    registration.setName("primeFacesFileUploadFilter");
    registration.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.FORWARD);
    registration.setServletNames(Collections.singleton(FACES_SERVLET_NAME));
    registration.setServletRegistrationBeans(Collections.singleton(facesServletServletRegistrationBean));
    return registration;
}

@Override
public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    servletContext.setInitParameter("facelets.DEVELOPMENT", Boolean.TRUE.toString());

    servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX", ".xhtml");
    servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE", "Development");
    servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD", "1");
    servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES", "/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml");
    servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS", Boolean.TRUE.toString());

    servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", Boolean.TRUE.toString());

    servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
    servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.THEME", "ui-lightness");
    servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.UPLOADER", "commons");
    servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.MOVE_SCRIPTS_TO_BOTTOM", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet> facesServletServletRegistrationBean() {
    ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet> servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new FacesServlet(), "*.xhtml");
    servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servletRegistrationBean.setName(FACES_SERVLET_NAME);
    return servletRegistrationBean;
}
```

I have also added commons dependencies to my pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please help me! Thanks in advance :)

[I get something like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S14lw.png)

Comment: So you debugged network traffic in the browser and it showed... what?

Comment: @Kukeltje https://i.stack.imgur.com/S14lw.png see here there are some updates as response

Comment: And the content? Is the file being uploaded? etc...

Comment: @Kukeltje i needed to change my configuration. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had something wrong with my configuration beans
Below properly configured beans:

```
 @Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean primeFacesFileUploadFilter(@Autowired ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet> facesServletServletRegistrationBean) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(new org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter(), facesServletServletRegistrationBean);
    registration.setName("primeFacesFileUploadFilter");
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    registration.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.REQUEST);
    return registration;
}

@Bean
public FacesServlet facesServlet() {
    return new FacesServlet();
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet> facesServletServletRegistrationBean(@Autowired FacesServlet facesServlet) {
    ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet> servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(facesServlet, "*.xhtml");
    servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servletRegistrationBean.setName(FACES_SERVLET_NAME);
    return servletRegistrationBean;
}
```

I needed to add facesServlet bean and i used two arguments constructor in FilterRegistrationBean. Also i removed this line

`registration.setServletRegistrationBeans(Collections.singleton(facesServletServletRegistrationBean));`

Comment: Please **explicitly** mention in text what needed to be changed. We don't have automatic 'diff' tools built into our brains ;-)